# Splitting ruby content with in_groups_of

Tags: ruby, each, middleman

I am using middleman's blog to output the summary of all blog posts on a page like so:

```
<ul> 
  <% page_articles.each_with_index do |article, i| %>
    <% unless article.data['tags'].include?('featured') %>
      <li class="Project">
        <h3><%= link_to article.title, article.url %></h3>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This works well, but I need to break after 3 entries like so:

```
<ul>
   <li class="Project"><li>
   <li class="Project"><li>
   <li class="Project"><li>
</ul>

<div class="break"></div>

<ul>
   <li class="Project"><li>
   <li class="Project"><li>
   <li class="Project"><li>
</ul>
```

From research, it seems that ruby's `in_groups_of` seems like the way to go here, but cannot get the syntax working properly. Here is what I have:

```
<ul> 
<% page_articles.in_groups_of(3, false).each_with_index do |article, i| %>
  <% unless article.data['tags'].include?('featured') %>
    <li class="Project">
      <h3><%= link_to article.title, article.url %></h3>
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

It is returning an `undefined method 'in_groups_of'`. Also, it seems like the unless logic should be applied before it is split into groups of three. Any thoughts on ways to improve this?

Comment: [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) will do this for you since you are using `false` as the `fill_with` argument. e.g. `page-articles.each_slice(3).with_index do |article,i|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of) is an `activesupport` extension added by Rails to allow you to split and access equal groups (`Array`) with a fixed number of elements (by default `nil` will fill the uneven split. e.g.

```
require "active_support/core_ext/array"
a = (1..5).to_a
a.in_groups_of(2) 
#=> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,nil]]
```

When you pass the second argument (`fill_with`) as `false` it no longer returns equal groups but rather splits the elements into groups of n elements and when the split is uneven the last group will be the remaining elements regardless of n.

```
require "active_support/core_ext/array"
a = (1..5).to_a
a.in_groups_of(2,false) 
#=> [[1,2],[3,4],[5]]
```

This non-equal grouping functionality is actually available without the use of `activesupport` through [`Enumberable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
a = (1..5).to_a
a.each_slice(2).to_a 
#=> [[1,2],[3,4],[5]]
require "active_support/core_ext/array"
a.in_groups_of(2,false)  == a.each_slice(2).to_a 
#=> true
```

Since you are specifying the second argument as `false` in this case instead of `require`-ing functionality you don't need I would recommend using `Enumerable#each_slice` as follows:

```
<ul> 
  <% page_articles.each_slice(3).with_index do |article, i| %>
    <% unless article.data['tags'].include?('featured') %>
      <li class="Project">
          <h3><%= link_to article.title, article.url %></h3>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This will function as requested without any additional overhead as `Enumerable` is part of the ruby core.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of) is not part of core Ruby, but added by Rails as part of Active Support Core extensions.

You can use Active Support extensions by requiring it.

```
require "active_support/core_ext/array"
```

Comment: Thanks. I included the gem, bundled, and showing a data error. So now, the issue is syntax. each_with_index seems to be clashing with in_groups_of

Comment: In my simple test, `in_groups_of` seems to work fine with `each_with_index`

Comment: `#in_groups_of` with `false` as the `fill_with` argument seems like you could just use `Enumerable#each_slice`  without the need for an additional require. e.g. `a = (1..5).to_a; a.in_groups_of(2,false) == a.each_slice(2).to_a; #=> true`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I suppose I need to qualify the unless statement first? So we are left with an array that we can manipulate?

Comment: @engineersmnky will you add as an answer? That did it.